# Android MediaStore date_taken start/end time

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am writing an Android app that allows a user to record a video, but then needs an accurate time at which the video was recorded. I want to use this to match the video to other sensor information on the device.

To start the video camera, I use the video capture intent:

```
private long intentTimestamp;

private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    intentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
}
```

On return from the video camera:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            // Get last recorded video from Gallery
            String date = getLastVideo();
            Log.d(TAG, "# onActivityResult: " + date);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Start intent: " + intentTimestamp
                    + ", video timestamp: " + date
                    + ". Difference: " + ((Long.parseLong(date) - intentTimestamp) / 1000) + "s",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "# onActivityResult: Cancelled");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "# onActivityResult: Video capture failed");
        }
    }

}
```

I call a function to return the date when the video was taken:

```
private String getLastVideo() {
    final Uri videoUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String[] videoColumns = {
            MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_TAKEN
        };
    final String videoOrderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID + " DESC";

    Cursor videoCursor = getContentResolver().query(videoUri, videoColumns, null, null, videoOrderBy);

    if (videoCursor != null) {
        if (videoCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int dateColumn = videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_TAKEN);
            return videoCursor.getString(dateColumn);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "# getLastVideo - videoCursor.moveToFirst() == false");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "# getLastVideo - videoCursor == null");
    }

    videoCursor.close();

    return null;
}
```

This uses the android MediaStore to get the [date taken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.html) (The date & time that the video was taken in units of milliseconds since jan 1, 1970.).

I have two HTC One's that I am testing on right now. One with the stock HTC rom installed, and one with the Google Edition rom. It appears that, on the GE rom, the date taken corresponds to time that I *start* recording the video. However, on the HTC rom, the date taken corresponds to the time at which I *ended* recording.

I can obtain the duration of the video from the MediaStore, which I could use to correct the HTC rom value, but how would I do this systematically across all Android devices? Is there somewhere else I could get a consistent video date taken (start or end)? Would I need to control the camera directly in my app, e.g. [Controlling the Camera](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)?

Comment: You can use the EXIF data to try and get the date. I'm not sure if the result would be any different and EXIF data isn't always guaranteed to exist (hence why im not posting this as an answer).  `ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()); String date = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);`

Comment: Thanks for the input @dymmeh. Does the ExifInterface work with video files? The docs talk about jpeg files primarily. I know information is often put in the file Exif data anyway. Nevertheless, the datetime tag returns null on my test device.

Comment: Hmm maybe that is only for images.. I assumed it was a common thing for all media in general. I guess I was wrong. Sorry about that.